c# & mysql Exception when calling a long query
I have a code piece to run a stored procedure in mysql. Code runs and completes when execution time is under 1 hour however when it takes more than 1 hour it gets an exception. I set command timeout to 7200 and I also tried to increase various other timeout parameters in code with following queries without any success:
SET SESSION wait_timeout=99999; SET SESSION interactive_timeout=99999;
set net_write_timeout=99999; set net_read_timeout=99999

When I use Dbeaver client procedure completes even if it takes more than 1 hour.
MySQL database version is 8.0.32.
I tried using both MySql.Data library (version 8.4.0) and MySqlConnector (version 2.3.7) with latest versions.
Code is as follows (.NET Framework 4.8):
     string sql = "CALL EDW.SP_DENEME_20240503(20240421,'M');";
                string connStr = @"Server=hostname;Port=port; Database=;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=pwd;AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true;Connect Timeout=120";
                using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
                using (MySqlCommand cancellableCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cancellableCommand.CommandTimeout = 7200;

                    conn.Open();
                    return cancellableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

Error message for MySql.Data:
Exception msg :Fatal error encountered during command execution.
Exception inner exc :Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
Exception stacktrace :   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__111.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__111.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.<ExecuteNonQueryAsync>d__100.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Error Message for MySqlConnector:
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Failed to read the result set. ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlEndOfStreamException: An incomplete response was received from the server
   at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.ProtocolUtility.<ReadPayloadAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Protocol/Serialization/ProtocolUtility.cs:line 429
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.<ReceiveReplyAsync>d__112.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 881
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.<ReadResultSetHeaderAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 37
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 133
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.<InitAsync>d__107.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 502
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 57
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.<ExecuteNonQueryAsync>d__78.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 309
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at DataAccess.MySqlDataAccess.<ExecuteProcedure>d__29.MoveNext() 

I expect the code to complete without errors as long as it takes less than command timeout (In my case, 2 hours)
